# sql select the distinct of 2 column pair

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say that I have 2 columns:

```
_______________
| id1  |  id2 |
|------|------|
|  1   |   2  |
|  2   |   1  |
|  3   |   4  |
|  4   |   1  |
|  4   |   3  |
|  1   |   4  |
      ...
```

If I have a row id1 = 1 and id2 = 2, there will be a row somewhere after it which will be id1 = 2 and id2 = 1.

How can I get the top of each (id1, id2) pair?

---

Update:

The result from the example should be:

```
row1: 1 | 2
row2: 3 | 4
row3: 4 | 1
```

Comment: What is the result set that you want to achieve ? it is not clear in the question .

Comment: what do u mean by "top of each" ?

Comment: do you only want those values? or do you want the other values for your table row as well?

Comment: If I a have more columns, I need their values. e.g. the first row of the example result will look like 1 | 2 | other value | another | and so on. If you are asking about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking back to the original table depends a lot on what is in that table that causes the order.  Lets says you have a date field or a sequence field and you want the smallest value...

In this example I assume seqField is unique by row

Then it looks like this:

```
--drop table #test

 SELECT 1 as seqField, 1 as id1, 2 as id2
 INTO #test
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2,2,1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3,3,4
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4,4,1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 5,4,3
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 6,1,4 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 7,10,20;

WITH norm AS 
( 
   SELECT CASE WHEN id1 > id2 THEN id1 ELSE id2 END as a,
          CASE WHEN id1 < id2 THEN id1 ELSE id2 END as b, * 
   FROM #test
), setList AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT a, b, min(seqField) as s
  FROM norm
  GROUP BY a, b
)
SELECT #test.* 
FROM #test
JOIN setList ON #test.seqField = setList.s
```

This gives

```
seq id1 id2
1   1   2
3   3   4
4   4   1
7   10  20
```

As sqlchan points out seqField can be replaced with `%%physloc%%` if you don't have an existing column to use.

Comment: This will destroy the order, shouldn't it? If (1, 2) is before (2, 1), I want to have as a result (1, 2). If (2, 1) is before (1, 2), then the result will be (2, 1)

Comment: @bliof - I've edited my answer -- see a functioning + tested example

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join to find the matching pair with `id1, id2` inverted:

```
select  t2.*
from    YourTable t1
join    YourTable t2
on      t2.id1 = t1.id2
        and t2.id2 = t1.id1
```

Comment: A filter does not work -- he wants to know what is filtered -- a list that gives him those values only once.

Comment: @Hogan: You're right, totally misread the question, rewrote answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just do:

```
SELECT `id1`, `id2`
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY `id1`, `id2`
ORDER BY `id1`, `id2`
```

ok, to get past the (1,2) and (2, 1) from showing up:

```
SELECT `id1`, `id2`
FROM `table`  a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 
    FROM `table` b 
    WHERE b.`id1` < b.`id2` AND b.`id1` = a.`id2` AND b.`id2` = a.`id1'
)
ORDER BY `id1`, `id2`
```

And if you want to actually keep the order so that the first row is shown, then you will need to use a `ROWID` (more info: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html )

```
SELECT id1, id2
FROM `table`  a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 
    FROM `table` b 
    WHERE b.ROWID < a.ROWID AND b.id1 = a.id2 AND b.id2 = a.id1
)
```

Results:

```
row1: 1 | 2
row2: 3 | 4
row3: 4 | 1
```

Comment: This would return both (1,2) and (2,1)

Comment: I fixed up my answer to account for this.

Comment: This is still wrong it returns 1,4 as the second row not 4,1 (and 4,1 should be the 3rd result)

Answer (score 0):

take distinct on `id1 + "|" + id2`. e.g. and this is just concept, I haven't tried it right now, `SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(id1,'|',id2)) FROM ...`. Seph's recommendation on group by would make more sense though

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008...

```
SELECT a.col1,a.col2
FROM answer a 
JOIN answer b ON a.col1 = b.col2 and b.col1 = a.col2
and a.%%physloc%% = (SELECT MIN(c.%%physloc%%) 
                     FROM  answer c WHERE c.col1 = a.col1 and c.col2 = a.col2)
and b.%%physloc%% = (SELECT MIN(c.%%physloc%%) 
                     FROM answer c WHERE c.col1 = b.col1 and c.col2 = b.col2)
ORDER BY CASE 
     WHEN a.col1 > a.col2 
     THEN a.col2 
     ELSE b.col2 
     END
```

However I wouldnt use %%physloc%% (too internalesque) - I'd introduce a rowid identity column if order is important.
For Oracle you can use ROWID and dont need to worry about adding a column.

Comment: I see that this won't return mutiple (1,2) but won't this return both (1,2) and (2,1)?

Comment: Ah - my apologies, first read - thats what I thought you needed.
Try this    SELECT a.col1,a.col2
    FROM answer a
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM answer b
                  WHERE b.col1 = a.col2
                  AND b.col2 = a.col1
                  AND a.%%physloc%% < b.%%physloc%%)
    AND a.%%physloc%% = (SELECT MIN(%%physloc%%)
                         FROM answer b
                        WHERE b.col1 = a.col1
                         AND b.col1 = a.col1)

Comment: That works except when there is a case of (x,y) without (y,x) -- see the test data on my example.